# How can I configure samba with separate hard drive?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, permissions, mount, samba

I am in the process of spinning up a CentOS box as a file server.  I had the smaller system hard drive already in the machine, installed CentOS, and installed Samba in preparation of my new, bigger HDD.  After verifying that samba was working I installed my new hard drive, modified my fstab, set up the share, and I get the following error message when I am attempting to access the share:

[image]

Believing this to be an issue with Windows or a firewall I attempted it from another linux box and received a similar error, that the folder does not exist or is inaccessible.
I double checked my permissions but the new folder on the new mounted hard drive (named Shares) shows it has the same permissions as the other folders which work.

[image]

Here is the line from fstab:

[image]

Here is the smb.conf file:

[image]

I know that the smb.conf file is ridiculous right now but I attempted to modify it based off of what was already working with the others (which obviously, it didn't) and just about every other permission I could find that could deny access to allow access to it.  After all that the only difference between it and the working folders is that it is being mounted from another hard drive.  Is there something else that I need to do or something I may have missed?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about you click that “See details” button and save us a little guesswork? ;)

Comment: Network name cannot be found.

Comment: Can you ping the box by name?  Did you restart samba service after configuring the new share, does the service name need access to the folder?

Comment: Can you Mount to it locally?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx It is mounted locally.  Fstab is working.  On the local box I can navigate to the directory and view and create files.  But through Samba it acts as though the path is incorrect though I confirmed it is the correct path.

Comment: @Optichip I can ping the box.  The other shares aside from the "Shares" folder are all working but they are on the system hdd.  I have restarted the services after each change.

Comment: What happens when you navigate to `\\rowsdower`? Do you see your `Shares` folder?

Comment: @BigChris Yes.  I can see the folder but I get the error above when I attempt to navigate it.  However, on the rowsdower box I am able to navigate into the folder.